# pretty: How did its Old English etymon semantically shift from 'a trick, wile, craft' to its Middle English etymon 'manly, gallant'?

Tags: etymology

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=pretty) contends  the semantic shift is 'uncertain', but what  semantic notions might've underlain  'a trick, wile, craft' with  'manly, gallant'?

**pretty**

> Old English prættig (West Saxon), pretti (Kentish), *prettig (Mercian) "cunning, skillful, artful, wily, astute," from prætt, *prett "a trick, wile, craft," from Proto-Germanic *pratt- (source also of Old Norse prettr "a trick," prettugr "tricky;" Frisian pret, Middle Dutch perte, Dutch pret "trick, joke," Dutch prettig "sportive, funny," Flemish pertig "brisk, clever"), of unknown origin.
>
> Connection between Old English and Middle English words is uncertain, but if they are the same, meaning had shifted by c. 1400 to "manly, gallant," and later moved via "attractive, skillfully made," to "fine," to "beautiful in a slight way" (mid-15c.). Ironical use from 1530s. For sense evolution, compare nice, silly. Also used of bees (c. 1400). "After the OE. period the word is unknown till the 15th c., when it becomes all at once frequent in various senses, none identical with the OE., though derivable from it" [OED].

Comment: probably as best you will get.  semantic shifts are freq. hard to document much less explain.

Comment: "Connection between Old English and Middle English words is uncertain" - there's the rub.

Comment: ***blazons***???

Comment: @Jim Why (do you think) not?

Comment: "seeking guesses" may be patently OT.

Comment: What do ***you*** think? And why is knowing how the meaning of praettig (pretty)  muted from *cunning* to *manly* to *attractive* particularly interesting to you? Have you searched any Old English or Middle English texts?

Answer (score 3):

Anatoly Liberman, renowned linguist and etymologist, traces the history of *pretty* from its Low German and Icelandic origins to its current meaning in English as an adjective, *pleasing* to the senses but not particularly striking, and as an  adverb; moderately sufficient or degree e.g. "pretty good", "pretty important", "pretty bad".

> The root of *pretty*, which must have sounded approximately like *prat*, meant “trick.” Judging by the cognates of *pretty* in Dutch, Low (Northern) German and Old Icelandic, the adjectives derived from this root first meant “sly, crafty, roguish, sportive.” […] Back **in Middle English**, ***the oldest recorded meaning developed from “crafty, wily, artful” to “clever, skillful” and “pleasing, fine, proper.”*** The original sense was forgotten.
>
> […] The line between “proper; physically fit” and “good-looking” is easy to cross. Thus, *handsome*, so obviously derived form *hand* and *some* with the meaning “handy, easy to handle,” soon changed to “apt, happy; considerable” and “beautiful” (“handsome is as handsome does”). Likewise, *clever* seems to have been coined with the meaning “brisk, sprightly,” but in the 17th century it could also mean “handsome.” Somewhere in this loose conglomeration of senses, we usually find “considerable.” The most colorless of them all, it allows us to use the adverb *pretty* in phrases like p*retty dark* and *pretty scary*, in which the idea of prettiness is suppressed and pretty means “quite.” Only a deliberate joke, a combination like *pretty ugly* makes one aware of how incongruous such word groups are.
>
> *[Oxford University Press Blog](https://blog.oup.com/2007/11/pretty/)*

Etymonline has an entry for *[pretty-boy](https://www.etymonline.com/word/pretty-boy#etymonline_v_47407)*, emphasis in bold mine.

> **pretty-boy**
> 1885 as an adjective, 1888 as a noun, from *pretty* (adj.) + *boy* (n.).
> In Middle English  **a** ***pretty man*** was "**a worthy or clever fellow.**"

The 9th century meaning of *pretty*; cunning, clever, skilful, persisted until the 19th century

> *In the end, however, it was a very **pretty** shot, right across the chasm; killed first fire, and the brute fell headlong into the brook…*
> 1877, *Bismarck his Authentic Biography* by Hesekiel and Taylor
> Source: *[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pretty)*

The shift from a cunning, astute or skilful man (*pretty-man*) to someone gallant (brave) and "manly" in Middle English is an almost organic segue.

The expression, *pretty boy*, has not become obsolete but today it conveys the rather effeminate beauty of a young man or his physical (and youthful) attractiveness.